# object caching vs cache database query results

Tags: caching

The question is mainly related to caching on the database side. Say, we did various performance optimization including query tuning, DB sharding, DB De-normalization etc. We still saw an need to have an in-memory cache on database side. We have 2 options for caching - cache database query results vs. Caching database (OR) business objects.

What are pros and cons of Caching an object like (user, product, address) vs. Caching an result-set returned by the query?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my experience, **caching application objects** has a considerable amount of benefits over caching raw query results.

If your application is already structured with a DAO layer which separates business logic from database access, it is quite easy to add a tiny caching layer on top of your DAOs using the Cache Proxy pattern (that is, providing an entity which implements the same interface of your DAO, handles the storage/retrieval from cache and delegates database access to the actual target entity if needed).

This approach leads to a series of key considerations in the design of the application:

- there is a clear separation of responsibilities between the database access logic, the caching layer and the business logic
- all details of the caching logic (key generation, storage policies and expiration management) are encapsulated in a separate entity
- you may choose to enable caching facilities selectively, e.g. only for some methods/DAOs
- the DAO and the Cache Proxy share the same interface, e.g. it is easy to switch cache on/off also at runtime
- you can test separately the DAO and the Cache Proxy

Being more practical, caching your application objects implies:

- when storing or retrieving objects you pay a single serialization/deserialization overhead, while when retrieving query results you still need to build your objects
- the complexity of your object (almost) doesn't matter (e.g. the Cache Proxy ignores that the DAO created the object with 3 separate queries on 2 different data sources)
- generating the cache key can be tricky in some cases, while hashing the query string (which you don't know in the Cache Proxy) is much easier
- the serialized object in cache (a json string, for example) can be read and used from other applications too (undesirable, but sometimes needed)
- chances are that your database already implements a complex and fast cache query mechanism, which you may want to tune for your needs instead of building another layer on top of it

You can build a caching layer for your DAOs on your own. If your application is already based on frameworks such as [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html), the caching support may be already built-in and you just need to setup proper configuration (although not always as flexible as you want).

Finally, I can't say using a query cache has particular disvantages over a well thought objects cache. Nevertheless, it should make me wonder the fact that a popular framework such as [Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch06.html#d5e1428) comes with the query cache disabled by default and the requirement to selectively enable it on individual queries.

Comment: Thank you for taking time for this explanation. It is crystal clear now.

Comment: I think one disadvantage of query cache might be the need to rebuild the cache if the query changes.

Comment: A change in the query may affect the cache in different ways depending on how you generate the cache key: if you generate it automatically using some hashing method on the query string, every single change in the string (even adding a whitespace) will affect the key; if you instead generate the cache key based on input parameters (which is possible both for query cache and object cache), the key need to be changed only if the change affects the result of the query or the content of your objects.

Comment: One more thing to take into account with objects cache (but this problem depends on the kind of serialization you use) is that a change in the interface of the object (regardless of the changes in the query) may need to be reflected in the cache key, because it may affect the serialization of the object (that is, you may end up reading old objects from cache which you're unable to deserialize).